# How to split string by string with multiple inverted commas in string in c#

Tags: c#

How to split a string by "," where " is part of string to split by.

```
         string[] stringSeparator = new string[] {","};
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
                string strline = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] _values = strline.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);

                for (int entry = 0; entry < _values.Length; entry++) {
                    MessageBox.Show(_values[entry]);
                }
            }
```

Tried to use "","" but it seems to return whole line instead of just part of it.

Edit:

String to split (example):

First line:

> "24446022020000000174234443,""PLN"",""NVESTMENT
>   SOMETHING
>   "",""2011-03-06"",""2011-03-07"",""-25,21"""

2nd line:

> "1,""E"",""2011-03-04"",""2011-03-07"",""2011-03-07"",""1,00"",""0000000100000001"",""UZNANIE
>   sdsd
>   ELIXIR"",""45555550040000001244580001"",""Some
>   Client (E)KLIENT
>   NR:0000000100000001"",""example
>   something"",""73116022447246000100000001"""

Comment: It would be clearer to us if you give us a (simple) string example for input and how you expect to split it.  I don't know if you want to split your strings by a double-quotation mark `"` or literally the double-quote, comma, double-quote `","`.

Comment: Looking at your example, I have provided an alternate code in my answer. It should work

Comment: I have given a short way to achieve it. Its tested and it works. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to represent literal quotation marks in a string, you need to escape it (or double it in a verbatim string literal).

i.e.,

```
new string[] { "\",\"" };
//or
new string[] { @""",""" };
```

---

As for why you're getting the values you were getting, consider the ways you were typing it:

```
string[] stringSeparator = new string[] { "," };
```

Is a string array containing a single string, just a comma `,`.  It will split but you probably didn't get the values you were expecting.

```
string[] stringSeparator = new string[] { "","" };
```

Is a string array containing a two strings, both empty (blank) strings.  Perhaps it would be clearer if it was typed as: `new string[] { "", "" };`.  The `Split()` function ignores empty string delimiters so it doesn't split anything.

```
string[] stringSeparator = new string[] { "\",\"" };
```

Is a string array containing a single string, double-quote comma double-quote `","`.  It should get you everything between the `","` in your strings.

Comment: @MadBoy: I've added an explanation as to why you were seeing the values that you were seeing.  Hopefully it would be clearer to you now.

Comment: Yes it's much clearer now. I've overlooked that "", "" is treated as 2 separate strings. Thanks a lot. Now I need to get rid of some of the " which are not really something I want :-)

Comment: @MadBoy: So does that mean you want to remove the quotes from each string in the results?  Would you mind showing us what strings you would expect in your results?  For example using this code, the first two strings in your first example would be `"24446022020000000174234443,""PLN"` and `"NVESTMENT SOMETHING"`.  Did you want these strings to be `24446022020000000174234443`, `PLN` and `NVESTMENT SOMETHING`?

Comment: Well " is not something i need. I need pure data to insert it into database. This data will be sent from bank and it seems that they include first line (as kind of summary) so most likely i will skip first line. It seems that text betweeen " " is what I need but when i tried to split by , only it was spliting 0,10  or 10,0 which is money that I need in non altered way. Spliting by "," seems good but i will need to cleanup any remaining "" as i presume they won't give me anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',', '"' };
string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters,
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim first and then split to get rid of all quotes.

```
string[] stringSeparator = new string[] {"\",\""};
while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{

    //trim removes first and last quote since they are not removed by the split
    string line = sr.ReadLine().Trim('"');
    string[] values = line.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int index = 0; index < values.Length; index++)
        MessageBox.Show(values[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strline = sr.ReadLine();              
string[] abc = strline.Split('"');
abc = Array.FindAll(abc, val => val != ",").ToArray();
string result[] = Array.FindAll(abc, val => val != "").ToArray();
```

Comment: First option gets me a lot of white spaces and bugs out on -25,21 which is split when it shouldn't be. 2nd option doesn't work. Complains about blank "" or something (compiler errors out).

Comment: @MadBoy: Edited the answer. I have given a short way to achieve it. Its tested and it works. Hope it helps

Comment: Is it really short way ? `string[] stringSeparator = new string[] {"\",\""};` seems to do the trick in one line :-)

Comment: @MadBoy: Yes but again u need to split into an array